# Do i really need to hash passwords?

Tags: database, passwords, hash, authentication

I am building a project, which has a pretty basic login system. There will NO REGISTRATION system available, the users will be added manually. Also i protected the databases data input gates very well. So after all, do i still need to hash and even salt the users passwords?

And if your answer is yes, the next question is why?

Comment: You must always assume that your system can be compromised and that an attack could read your database. Then consider the consequences. It's bad enough even if you do everything right, but if you store plain passwords then the consequences will go much further than "just" your system.

Comment: As a general rule, it's very important to get used to good practices, esp. those that are easy to implement. If you think, *this is a simple project, why care?*, you'll get used to sloppy coding and you'll end up omitting such practices in all cases.

Comment: "Also i protected the databases data input gates very well": Did you also protect all other possibilities of accessing the database? Is it protected from system administrators, your hosting service provider, hackers attacking your frontend, are backups safe etc. Many additional problems that can be avoided by implementing a simple hashing.

Comment: actually, when i said, i protected all of the possibilities that i can imagine. I am the service provider, the software is really simple, it just accepts a username and password from only a domain, so "data input gates" are protected pretty well. But of course there could be a possibility that an attacker may find another way that i cannot see now. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you generate the password for each user and do not let the user change the password, then you can make a case for not hashing them.

However:

- You will have to explain to everyone that audits the system why you are not hashing the passwords.
- You will have to have some way of proving that a system admin did not look at a user’s password then logon as the user.
- A lot of programmers will think you don’t know what you are doing.
- What if the system is changed at some point, or the code gets copied into another system.

I think of this like crossing a road.

> You always look both ways even if the
>   green man says it is OK to cross.

(It is quicker to look both ways, then explain to any watching children etc why you don’t need to in this case)

Comment: thank you, this is the point i was trying to get, but also the 'what if' sentences are bad enough, so hashing is cool :D

Answer (score 11):

Well, what would be the consequence of an intruder being able to impersonate another user? Weigh those consequences against the difficulty (which isn't very great) of adding hashing and salting.

One risk which you may want to consider is that if a user has the same password on multiple sites, then their security is only as safe as the weakest site. Even if you're manually assigning the passwords yourself (and not allowing the user to choose it) they may go on to use the same password in other sites.

Comment: as users tend to reuse their passwords, it's also about impersonating users on other sites/systems - only if passwords aren't auto-generated though.

Comment: @sfussenegger: My point in the second paragraph was that even if the password is autogenerated on *this* site, a user could still reuse it on another site.

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely. It's one of the most important obligations to your users you have to honor - to treat their personal data very carefully.

Comment: It's not only something to honor but also something that is legally required in many countries.

Comment: I guess it is good if you principles even exceed legal requirements.

Answer (score 5):

In some jurisdictions/industries, storing login credentials in plain text could be a violation of data protection laws.  If you're doing something like that in the US on a system that has even the slightest bit to do with medical or financial records, and you get audited, even if there's been no breach, you'll be lucky if the worst that happens is your clients and suppliers refuse to do business with you until your systems pass audit.  There could be hefty fines as well.  Even if your system *doesn't* work with sensitive data, if it's intended for use by people who routinely work with such data, the possibility that they may reuse passwords that are also used to access regulated data would at the very least make an auditor very nervous, and make their client extremely reluctant to work with you, even if you were technically in compliance.

Comment: Same point applies to the UK too- possibly EU mandated, can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because your database is still there and a user system and its database are no more difficult to compromise without a registration form than with one.

Even if you protect your "database data input gates" very well, your database still isn't 100% attacker-proof. If someone still manages to slip through your defenses and sees everything in your database, and all the passwords are in plain text, your users' accounts are still compromised. By hashing them at least you're costing attackers more time, **and** at the same time protecting your users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because, e.g., people having access to the database can easily impersonate other users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because there is always risk of compromising database. Remember, that many people uses the same password for many sites, IMs etc so you are making risk for not only information in your system.

Answer (score 1):

People use their same password for more than just your site as well. If an attacker gets the passwords, there are more consequences than just your site. That user's email, bank accounts, etc may also be compromised. Do the diligent thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you hash passwords? It protects you, your staff and your users and it costs almost nothing to implement. Users have a right to expect that your system administrators / DBAs / whoever cannot see their passwords and your administrators have a right not to be exposed to that information needlessly. In any internal/external technical security audit one of the first things the auditors will do is home in on any password columns in the database and determine whether they are hashed or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Also i protected the databases data input gates very well.

I bet every system designer/administrator for every compromised password file in the history of computing thought the same thing.